# CDate() throws an exception after checking IsDate()

Tags: excel, vba

My code - from this site - crashes if it does not get `IsDate` format. I need a loop to keep asking for `IsDate` entry.

Can the below be put in a do until loop?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Not IsDate(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MsgBox "Date required"
        Cancel = True
    End If
    'Display value in another textbox for testing purposes
    TextBox2.Text = Format(CDate(TextBox1.Text), "dd/mm/yyyy")
End Sub
```

Not skilled with loop syntax.

Keeps looping until `IsDate` entry is entered.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand you but looks like all you need to do is add `Exit Sub` after `Cancel = True`. Alternatively, you can place the line `TextBox2.Text = ...` in an `Else` branch. It doesn't seem like a loop is needed.

Comment: Your question is very contradictory. Do you want to force a user to enter a valid date or not? If you remove the line for testing purposes it will keep asking the user for a date.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a loop to keep asking for `IsDate` entry.

Since you're using the `TextBox1_Exit` event, you don't really need a loop for it to keep asking the user to enter a valid date when it's not. It will indeed do so whenever the user tries to leave `TextBox1`.

The problem with your code is that even though you set `Cancel = True`, you still reach the line that sets `TextBox2.Text` because `Cancel = True` doesn't automatically exit the Sub. What you need to do is either exit the Sub immediately after `Cancel = True` or place the next line in an `Else` branch.

You can either use something like this:

```
If Not IsDate(TextBox1.Text) Then
    MsgBox "Date required"
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If
'Display value in another textbox for testing purposes
TextBox2.Text = Format(CDate(TextBox1.Text), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Or this:

```
If Not IsDate(TextBox1.Text) Then
    MsgBox "Date required"
    Cancel = True
Else
    'Display value in another textbox for testing purposes
    TextBox2.Text = Format(CDate(TextBox1.Text), "dd/mm/yyyy")
End If
```

Comment: The first one worked very well.  The second did not. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: @Bzltyr They both do the exact same thing in the context of your question. That being said, it's probably more readable to swap the branches (i.e., `If IsDate() Then TextBox2.Text = ... : Else : MsgBox "Date required" ...`).

Comment: Thank you. I will look at that.  I usually stop thinking about something once it works. It works because of you so, thanks again.

Comment: @Bzltyr Glad I was able to help.